# determining test coverage with py.test + gevent

Tags: python, code-coverage, gevent, pytest

How can one get an accurate test coverage report when using `py.test` + `gevent`?

I've already tried the obvious thing, using the `pytest-cov` plugin for `py.test`, but it [generates inaccurate reports when gevent is in use](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pytest-dev/2013-April/002226.html).

Comment: +1 I have the exact same issue... I tried using git+https://github.com/newbrough/coverage.git and that actually worked great but recently pytest is complaining that the version is too old and fails.

Answer (score 8):

The [gevent coverage issue](https://bitbucket.org/ned/coveragepy/issue/149/coverage-gevent-looks-broken) was fixed in `coveragepy` recently.

However, `pytest-cov` fails to run with `coverage>=4`.

One possible fix, is to run `py.test` with the later versions of `coverage.py` without using the `pytest-cov` plugin.

First, install `coverage >= 4` and uninstall the `pytest-cov` plugin:

```
pip install --pre --upgrade coverage
pip uninstall pytest-cov
```

Add the following setting to `.coveragerc`:

```
[run]
concurrency = gevent
```

Then run with:

```
coverage run -m py.test
```

(instead of the regular `py.test` run)